# How to restart the for loop

Tags: python

I was trying to insert 5 subjects marks of multiple students into 2D array, and check their total and average marks, so I managed to insert into 2D array, but the loops will keep adding the marks of the previous students, which I assume it's because of the sum += student[x]. For example, the marks of first student got no issue with, but the marks of second students will be adding by the first student marks. What should I use to avoid this?

```
NUM = int (input ("Enter the number of students in the class:"))
student_list = []

for x in range (0, NUM):
    print ("Student", x+1,":")
    name = input ("Please enter student's name:") 
    tp_number = input ("Please enter student's TP number:")
    eim_marks = int (input ("Please enter EIM marks:"))
    csa_marks = int (input ("Please enter CSA marks:"))
    das_marks = int (input ("Please enter DAS marks:"))
    pwp_marks = int (input ("Please enter PWP marks:"))
    os_marks = int (input ("Please enter OS marks:"))

student_list.append([name,tp_number,eim_marks,csa_marks,das_marks,pwp_marks,os_marks])

sum = 0

for student in student_list:
    for x in range (2,len (student)):
        sum += student [x]
        average_marks = sum/5
    print (sum,average_marks)
```

Comment: Bring this `sum = 0` statement inside the outer `for` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Set sum to zero inside the loop**

```
NUM = int (input ("Enter the number of students in the class:"))
student_list = []

for x in range (0, NUM):
    print ("Student", x+1,":")
    name = input ("Please enter student's name:") 
    tp_number = input ("Please enter student's TP number:")
    eim_marks = int (input ("Please enter EIM marks:"))
    csa_marks = int (input ("Please enter CSA marks:"))
    das_marks = int (input ("Please enter DAS marks:"))
    pwp_marks = int (input ("Please enter PWP marks:"))
    os_marks = int (input ("Please enter OS marks:"))

student_list.append([name,tp_number,eim_marks,csa_marks,das_marks,pwp_marks,os_marks])



for student in student_list:
    sum = 0
    for x in range (2,len (student)):
        sum += student [x]
        average_marks = sum/5
    print (sum,average_marks)
```